# Pika got authentication_failure when publish

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a rabbit server installed with just one user (admin ad administrator) that have a verry simple password

Created a queue, and try to publish to it successfuly via rabbit web ui.

when I try to publish using pika, it's fail.
the connection is success ... means no problem with credential
But the basicPublish fail.

here is from the rabbit log.

> 2018-02-20 23:57:46.626 [info] <0.10379.0> connection <0.10379.0>
>   (127.0.0.1:40350 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'admin' authenticated and
>   granted access to vhost '/' 2018-02-20 23:57:46.626 [debug]
>   <0.10378.0> Supervisor {<0.10378.0>,rabbit_connection_helper_sup}
>   started rabbit_channel_sup_sup:start_link() at pid <0.10383.0>
>   2018-02-20 23:57:46.627 [debug] <0.10385.0> Supervisor
>   {<0.10385.0>,rabbit_channel_sup} started
>   rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.77879>, 1, 131072,
>   rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.10379.0>, {<<"127.0.0.1:40350 ->
>   127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}, true) at pid <0.10386.0> 2018-02-20 23:57:46.627 [debug] <0.10385.0> Supervisor {<0.10385.0>,rabbit_channel_sup}
>   started rabbit_limiter:start_link({<<"127.0.0.1:40350 ->
>   127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at pid <0.10387.0> 2018-02-20 23:57:46.627 [debug] <0.10385.0> Supervisor {<0.10385.0>,rabbit_channel_sup}
>   started rabbit_channel:start_link(1, <0.10379.0>, <0.10386.0>,
>   <0.10379.0>, <<"127.0.0.1:40350 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,
>   rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1,
>   {user,<<"admin">>,[administrator],[{rabbit_auth_backend_internal,none}]},
>   <<"/">>,
>   [{<<"connection.blocked">>,bool,true},{<<"authentication_failure_close">>,bool,true},{<<"consumer...">>,...},...],
>   <0.10380.0>, <0.10387.0>) at pid <0.10388.0>

Kindly please give me any enlightenment.

Sincerely
-bino-

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ, Erlang, and Pika are you using? Could you please provide the complete Python code you are using to reproduce this? FYI the RabbitMQ team monitors [this mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @LukeBakken. Sorry i'm in situation that can not access to my server. As far as I remember : OS = Debian Jessie, Rabbit installed from PackageCloud repository and I didn't set erlang repo. Pika installed using pip. Python is 3.6 running in pipenv. The code I use is a copy paste from rabbitMQ site. BTW, I found no problem when I use kombu and pub to exchange.

Comment: This is still not enough information. What you have posted is not an error or stack trace, either, just some debug statements in the RabbitMQ log. _Exactly_ what Python code are you using? What failure are you getting when you try basicPublish? Please provide the complete log somewhere - snippets won't help Again, there is no failure listed above.

Comment: @LukeBakken , I really appreciate your help. Kindly please ignore this thread, because I really need to work on another problem. I apologize for this.